# JSF: Showing page while backingBean is still working

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, backing-beans

maybe this title is not really precise, but here's the problem.
I'm doing some JSF project and I need a following:

When user logs on my application (ie. when he navigates to Home page), a method, which gets some money exchange rates from the internet and/or database, needs to be called. The execution of that method (page parsing, data saving etc.) lasts about 5-6 seconds. I don't want that navigation from Login to Home page lasts 5-6 seconds, i want one of these (didn't decide which one yet) to happen:

1) When user logs in, he sees Home page (immediately, not after 5-6 seconds) and is able to click and/or navigate while method is working in background.

2) When user logs in, he sees Home page (immediately), some loading sign in one part of the page and after method is executed, he sees dataTable with exchange rates.

Question is, **how to do any of this**?
If I put that method in HomePageBean constructor, page wont be displayed until method is executed. Maybe i can put some invisible element on Home page and call that method within some Getter, but i don't know if that's the right way to do (seems like hack) or will it actually work.

I'm using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ApplicationScoped bean like in example below:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "exchRateBean", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExchRateBean  {

  public List<Rate> getRates(Date date) {
    // cached data or DAO methods here
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    // Initial web-app initialization, will run once upon deploy
  }
}
```

And here is your backing bean accessing application-scoped bean.

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean  {
  @ManagedProperty(value="#{exchRateBean}")
  private ExchRateBean exchRateBean;

  // your JSF methods
  public List<Rate> getRates(Date date) {
    return getExchRateBean().getRates(date);
  }

  // G&S
  public ExchRateBean getExchRateBean() {
    return exchRateBean;
  }

  public void setExchRateBean(ExchRateBean exchRateBean) {
    this.exchRateBean = exchRateBean;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm not sure i understand completely. Does MyBean represent LoginBean/HomePageBean and my ExchRate dataTable is fetching data from MyBean.rates? If this is true, than it maybe solves the 2. part (i'll try it today) assuming it shows Home page and blank dataTable instantly and populates dataTable after getRates(date) is executed. But, what with 1., ie. where to call your getRates(date) method?

Comment: @Nikola MyBean is your LoginBean/HomePageBean, whereas ExchRate bean is one for whole site. It provides common methods and data which can be consumed by other beans. In this case MyBean is fetching rates from ExchRate. As for delay - you could init (@PostConstruct) and maintain rates hash(cache) in app scoped bean allowing fast response to MyBean and any other beans interested in exch rates.

Comment: There are other solutions like ajax background loading but not in your particular case. Rates are impersonal, the same for all users/requests (I believe), and it'd be pretty strange if site needs to think few second to show simple exchange rate table :)